# Form input requiring field to not be null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am shifting my app from rails 4.2 to 5.2, in this transition I have stumbled across an error that I am not sure how to fix. This bit of code was written for me as I had no clue for to accomplish it at the time. My table is for people, within that table are bosses and non bosses and those non bosses need to be able to be attached to the bosses.

In the new development area, when I submit my form for updating a person that "Boss" needs to be `null` I get the following:
`1 error prohibited this person from being saved: Boss must exist`

Controller:

```
def edit
    @person = Person.find(params[:id])
end
```

Model:

```
belongs_to :boss, class_name: 'Person'
has_many :subordinates, class_name: 'Person', foreign_key: 'boss_id'

validates_presence_of :user_name, :position, :fname, :lname
```

Schema:

```
t.integer "boss_id"
t.index ["boss_id"], name: "index_people_on_boss_id"
```

Form:

```
<% if @person.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
            <h2><%= pluralize(@person.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this person from being saved:</h2>

            <ul>
                <% @person.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                  <li><%= msg %></li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>

    <fieldset>
        ...many fields...
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <label>
            Boss
            <%= f.select :boss_id, [[" ", :null], [name, 1], [name, 2], ...etc ] %>
        </label>
    </fieldset>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

I am not sure where else to look for an answer to this.

Comment: Show the code of your form.

Comment: @MaxVinícius Form code added to post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Belongs_to require parent object to be present by default on the time of creation. If you'll create a child object without a parent, you will get ["must exist"] error message, so your object is not valid.

If you want this kind of behavior you will need to pass this option:

```
#person.rb
belongs_to :boss, class_name: 'Person', optional: true
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you!! I am curious, I am new to a lot of this, the above code that I was using worked in 4.2, did something change in the updates to 5.2 that made this code need the optional modifier? Thanks!!

Comment: @lostrennie Take a look at this gem: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form

Comment: @lostrennie this was introduced in Rails 5: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/18937/commits/6576f7354e50afb79881aaf3a6f50f4e81dfab70